# Connection for ceiling fan with remote and two light switches

Tags: ceiling-fan

I replaced an old fan/light that could be turned on from two different switches. The new fan/light has a remote. The are two black wires twisted together, two red wires twisted together and two white wires coming from the ceiling. The remote only has a black and white wire to connect. What is the correct configuration for this? I don't necessarily need to use the wall switches, but it would be nice.

Comment: Are you dead-set on having the remote in play?

Comment: I would rather have the remote as opposed to the switch/switches. There are no chains to control the fan speeds.

Comment: How will you comply with building codes that require a switch on the wall turn on at least one light in the room?    Also can you shoot us a photo of what's going on in thefan box and at least one of the switch boxes?  We are also keenly interested in which wires are on the brass screws vs black screw.    Don't unhook any wires.

Comment: USA or other colour code?

Comment: there doesn't seem like enough wires. what controls did the old fan have?

Comment: Harper. There is another light.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep one light switch to be within code compliance, and cap the other one off. That way you have a way to power off the unit to change light bulbs, etc. Then leave this on all the time so you can use the remote. Cap the red in the ceiling, and at the switch you plan to keep. This is your traveler to the other switch. Just use black, white and ground.